# Why my procedure not work with floats, error numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: oracle, plsql

This a code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_GOOD (
    P_GOOD_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    P_CLIENT_ID IN NUMBER,
    P_GOOD_PRICE IN NUMBER,
    P_GOOD_DATE IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
    )
IS
CUR_ID NUMBER(8);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ЕСТЬ!');
    /* Commented code */

END ADD_GOOD;
```

When i execute this:

```
EXECUTE ADD_GOOD('some text...', 28, 920);
EXECUTE ADD_GOOD('some text...', 28, 2400.00, '08.01.2018');
```

I get error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
```

Why? I think number support integer and float values?

Comment: Do you get the error with both the procedure calls? (pay attention to the date parameter)

Comment: `'08.01.2018'` is not a date, it is a string. If you want to pass a date then use a date literal `DATE '2018-01-08'`.

Comment: I have error only for second call.

Comment: When i add to '920' point and two zero i get errors for first call

Comment: What are your NLS settings? `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`

Comment: Which one you need? (
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ,
NLS_COMP = BINARY                                  
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = BYTE                                    
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP = FALSE ...)

Comment: Guess... we are talking about DATE, so it would be `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: Here... DD.MM.RR But my problim its not about DATE when i delete point and zero my code run "perfect" - its strange... i start thinkin about MS encoding "magic things"...

Comment: Are you passing 920 (or 920.00) as a number, as you've shown in the question, or as a string as your earlier comment suggests? If you're passing as a string then NLS settings would matter for the implicit conversion (specifically `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`); but as with the date, you should be passing the right data type, not relying on implicit conversion.

Comment: As number, code in my SQL Developer exacly same for my question code. I just add TO_DATE function instead string with date.

Comment: I ty replace 920.00 to TO_NUMBER('920.00') and still have a error... Maybe i make mistake when declare PROCEDURE parametry?

Comment: Delete lines from your procedure until you get to the minimum needed to replicate the problem. If you delete the `P_GOOD_NAME`, `P_CLIENT_ID` and `P_GOOD_DATE` parameters can you still replicate the problem? What about the `CUR_ID` local variable? Find the minimum needed to replicate and then **edit your question** to reflect this so we are not getting distracted by irrelevant things like date formats.  Then look a the relevant NLS settings to what is left in your minimal procedure and also **edit those values** into your question (if you aren't sure then just put them all in).

Comment: When i delete all parametry except for P_GOOD_PRICE and delete local var i still have error:
ORA-06502: 
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).

Comment: As you stated the value on NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is =',' in your case should be NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.' . As it is now it should work with TO_NUMBER('920,00') .

Comment: When i delete all parametry except for P_GOOD_PRICE and delete local var and rewrote EXECUTE to "EXECUTE ADD_GOOD(TO_NUMBER('920,00'));" WTF? And if i return all code and commented code its work with TO_NUMBER. But Why i cant just wrote number in float format?

Comment: The NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS sets the decimal and thousands markers. It should be set equal to ='.,' to work like you want it to work. If you execute ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,'; It should work as itendend for your session.

Comment: Last comment its answer - all work. Thanks!

Comment: @AlessandroVecchio - the NLS parameter doesn't apply to numeric literals, only to explicit or implicit `to_number()` calls. So it shouldn't have a problem if the literal `920.00` (without quotes) is passed in to a `number` argument.

Comment: @Alex Poole - things normally works as you said, but hundreds of bugs do exist related the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS parameter not having the common '.,' values and many depend on client to server conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Date in varchar '08.01.2018', there are no problem with floats.

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE ADD_GOOD (
    P_GOOD_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    P_CLIENT_ID IN NUMBER,
    P_GOOD_PRICE IN NUMBER,
    P_GOOD_DATE IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
    )
IS
CUR_ID NUMBER(8);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ЕСТЬ!');
    /* Commented code */

END ADD_GOOD;
BEGIN
    ADD_GOOD('some text...', 28, 920);
    ADD_GOOD('some text...', 28, 2400.00, SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

Comment: Its work with "VARCHAR" DATE and without it. If i add point and two zero to third parametr in first EXECUTE i give a error.

Comment: Maybe i have wrong character settings? I mean i type by russian keyboard and its about encoding? But numeric and '.' in ASCII range...

Answer (score -1):

```
EXECUTE ADD_GOOD('some text...', 28, 2400.00, to_date('08-Jan-2018'));
```

will work. you need to convert your string to date

```
 numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

error usually come when casting fails

Comment: i try it. Problem not about date. About float in procedure parametry.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer - especially since the OP has stated that the problem occurs when they call the procedure using `EXECUTE ADD_GOOD('some text...', 28, 920.00);` and the date is `NULL`.

Comment: User state that "I have error only for second call. " . its not the floating point. "Fixed-point or floating-point number with absolute value in range 1E-130 to (but not including) 1.0E126. A NUMBER variable can also represent 0." is official oracle document state this when defining the number.